# Insert operation is not working using NLog configuration

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, nlog

I am trying to configure database using NLog. Below is the complete code from NLog.config file:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      throwExceptions="true"
      internalLogLevel="Trace"
      internalLogFile="..\..\..\Logs\nlog-app.log">

    <targets>
    <!-- file targets -->
    <target name="asyncFile" xsi:type="AsyncWrapper">
      <target xsi:type="File" name="f" fileName="${basedir}/Log/${shortdate}.log"
            layout="${longdate} ${uppercase:${level}} ${message} ${aspnet-user-identity}"/>
      </target>

    <!-- database targets -->
      <target name="database" xsi:type="Database" keepConnection="true" useTransactions="true"
                   dbProvider="System.Data.SqlClient"
                   connectionString="Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=Test;Integrated Security=SSPI"
                    commandText="insert into MyLog(CreateDate,LogLevel,log_logger,Message) values(@time_stamp, @level, @logger, @message)">


        <parameter name="@time_stamp" layout="${date}" />
        <parameter name="@level" layout="${level}" />
        <parameter name="@logger" layout="${logger}" />
        <parameter name="@message" layout="${message}" />
      </target>
    </targets>
  <rules>
    <!-- add your logging rules here -->
    <logger name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="asyncFile,database" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
```

Table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE MyLog
(
    [CreateDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [Origin] [varchar](200) NULL,
    [LogLevel] [varchar](100) NULL,
    [log_logger] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [Message] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [Exception] [varchar](8000) NULL,
    [StackTrace] [varchar](8000) NULL,
)
```

Since the configuration is given in config file, so could not able to figured out the error. So please let me know this issue with possible solution.

Comment: Can you show your logger configuration also? (If it's not too big, the entire nlog configuration would be preferable)

Comment: @ Damien,  I have added the complete code from NLog.config file